# Replace data in word doc using Java

Tags: java, ms-word

How can I replace data in MS word doc template?
I've seen an article but it uses Maven library, for some reason it didn't work for me. [article link](https://thecodeexamples.com/java/generate-word-document-from-java/)

Meanwhile, I'm using Apache POI library, how can I approach the same result as the article mentioned above?

(I know how to create MS word doc in java, but the formatting is not easy so I'm thinking to use ready tamplete & replace the data that I want)

**Edit**
I'm facing a problem, as I don't get my desire output.
Here's the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, InvalidFormatException, IOException {
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("/Users/sam/Desktop/input.docx"));
    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
        for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
            String text = run.getText(0);
            text = text.replace("$name", "Sam");
            text = text.replace("$id", "1001");
            run.setText(text);
            System.out.println(text);
            }
        }
    document.write(new FileOutputStream("output.docx"));            
}
```

My word doc contains:

```
Your Name: $name
Your Id: $id
```

Output, is exactly like this:(

```
Your Name: $
n
ame
Your Id: 1001
```

Answer (score 0):

I doublecheked your code, it's work. I only replaces `setText` with `setText(text,0)` because in my case text duplicated.

```
 XWPFDocument document = new 
 XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("/home/tirex/document.docx"));
    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
        for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
            String text = run.getText(0);
            text = text.replace("$name", "Sam");
            text = text.replace("$id", "1001");
            run.setText(text,0);
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
```

Maybe problem in your doc file.

btw. i am author site in your link, you can simply write in comments if you have problems with code samples.